# Adding rotations onto a vector

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems

I have a vector with spherical co-ordinates $(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$, then I want this vector to be rotated by $\theta_2$ $\phi_2$ spherical angles but I cannot figure out how. I have tried using the rotational matrices

\begin{alignat}{1}
R_z(\phi_2) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \phi_2 &  -\sin \phi_2 & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \phi_2 & \cos \phi_2 & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
then\\
R_y(\theta_2) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta_2 & 0 & \sin \theta_2 \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \theta_2 & 0 & \cos \theta_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

but this does not reproduce \begin{alignat}{1}
V_{new} &=|V| \begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta_2\cos\phi_2 \\[3pt]
\sin\theta_2\sin\phi_2\\[3pt]
\cos\theta_2\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

when multiplied by a unit vector

\begin{alignat}{1}
V &=|V| \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\[3pt]
0\\[3pt]
1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: I think the rotations should give $(r_1,\theta_1+\theta_2,\phi_1+\phi_2)$ acting on $(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$

Comment: Your proposed answer looks a lot like it's a rotation around $r$ only, see http://www.iac.ethz.ch/edu/courses/bachelor/veranstaltungen/environmental_fluid_dynamics/AD3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation matrices you used only apply to rotations around cartesian axes (x,y,x). You cannot generalize it to spherical coordinates in the way you did. See page 4 [here](http://www.iac.ethz.ch/edu/courses/bachelor/veranstaltungen/environmental_fluid_dynamics/AD3) for the rotation matrix in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wish to express matrix addition with matrix multiplication.

This is done with adding extra (service) dimension, which components are always `1` for vectors.

$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1& a_2& a_3 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\times 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
b_{41} & b_{42} & b_{43} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1+b_{41}\\
a_2+b_{42}\\
a_3+b_{43}\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

You can ignore this forth dimension in all cases except calculating the rotation.